# How can I get a list of objects related to a min from a Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a Linq Query that is working as intended, but I need to add the code so that it will show me ONLY the people with the less cases assigned for an app that is been used to treat customers inquiries. The idea behind the query is so that it will let me automatically assign inquiries randomly between those agents which have less assigned issues to cover.

As a simple example, lets say I have 5 agents with just 1 case each, I need to randomly assign one of them to an Inquire which has currently no agent assigned. So all I'm looking for is a way to actually get all the agents with the smallest number of cases assigned.

So far this is the full proof of concept code:

```
var inquires = new List<Inquire>();
var agents = new List<Agent>();

LoadData();

var assignationsPerAgent = (from agent in agents 
                        join inq in inquires on agent equals inq.AssignedAgent into agentsInInquires
                        select new {
                            o_agent = agent,
                            casesAssignedTo = agentsInInquires.Count()
                        }).ToList();


//This works but is NOT the kind of solution I'm looking for
var min = assignationsPerAgent.Min(c => c.casesAsignedTo);
var agentWithMin = assignationsPerAgent.Where(a => a.casesAsignedTo == min);

Console.WriteLine();

void LoadData()
{
    agents = new(){
        new Agent{ Id = Guid.Parse("317d3d26-25c2-49da-aa4b-b7e49a1b9015"), Name = "Robert" },
        new Agent{ Id = Guid.Parse("84188e21-8147-498f-bc2a-59874dc4a24a"), Name = "Corina" },
        new Agent{ Id = Guid.Parse("90ca6658-95d4-4df4-a072-159087feddc0"), Name = "John" },
        new Agent{ Id = Guid.Parse("34e091e4-cc7a-4222-9885-5de5bb5a0291"), Name = "Jack"},
        new Agent{ Id = Guid.Parse("f22dcb4e-e927-4ddf-ae66-f37c0de6753d"), Name = "Samuel"}
    };

    inquires = new(){
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Paula", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("317d3d26-25c2-49da-aa4b-b7e49a1b9015"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Barry", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("84188e21-8147-498f-bc2a-59874dc4a24a"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Bertie", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("84188e21-8147-498f-bc2a-59874dc4a24a"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Herman", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("90ca6658-95d4-4df4-a072-159087feddc0"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Ashley", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("317d3d26-25c2-49da-aa4b-b7e49a1b9015"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Tate", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("90ca6658-95d4-4df4-a072-159087feddc0"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Bonnie", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("90ca6658-95d4-4df4-a072-159087feddc0"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Tabitha", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("90ca6658-95d4-4df4-a072-159087feddc0"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Ashley", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("34e091e4-cc7a-4222-9885-5de5bb5a0291"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Josie", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("84188e21-8147-498f-bc2a-59874dc4a24a"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Kelly", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("84188e21-8147-498f-bc2a-59874dc4a24a"))},
        new Inquire{ CustomerName = "Kelly", AsignedAgent = agents.Single(a => a.Id == Guid.Parse("f22dcb4e-e927-4ddf-ae66-f37c0de6753d"))},
    };
}

#nullable disable
class Inquire
{
    private Guid _id;

    public Guid Id 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        private set 
        {
            _id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
    
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Agent AsignedAgent { get; set; }
}

#nullable disable
class Agent
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Please take in consideration that the assignationsPerAgent variable is simulating data coming from a query in the database (The actual query is below). If the "easy" way to do this comes from the SQL that it's also an acceptable solution.

```
SELECT u.Id, COUNT(g.Id) as QtyAsig
FROM Users as u
LEFT JOIN GeneralInquires AS g ON u.Id = g.UserId
GROUP BY u.Id
ORDER BY COUNT(g.Id)
```

What I'm getting from this Query is:

```
Id                                      QtyAsig
8A21A6D2-0CEC-4F5C-2A6B-08DA60967E94    1
323C8D1A-2FAE-4ECC-D7A2-08DA6098F19A    1
BA485F3C-C44A-4FE5-9BFA-08DA64EF283A    1
8F0E856E-FA0B-4167-BBEF-08DA6451FA81    2
40952727-5C76-4902-9C4F-08DA638B3068    3
DD51085A-5BE3-4872-F4B5-08DA6E7828AA    4
```

What I need is:

```
Id                                      QtyAsig
8A21A6D2-0CEC-4F5C-2A6B-08DA60967E94    1
323C8D1A-2FAE-4ECC-D7A2-08DA6098F19A    1
BA485F3C-C44A-4FE5-9BFA-08DA64EF283A    1
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Linq doesn't require one statement and splitting results has no impact on performance.  Try following :

```
            List<Inquire> sortedInquires = inquires.OrderBy(x => x.AsignedAgent.Id).ToList();

            var results = (from a in agents
               //join i in sortedInquires on a.Id equals i.Id
               join i in sortedInquires on a.Id equals i.AssignedAgent
               select new { agent = a, inquires = i}
            ).GroupBy(x => x.agent.Id)
            .Select(x => x.First())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: It came out empty, but thanks for the info about impact on performance.

Comment: Be aware that if you move this to a database context, prematurely calling `ToList` will impact performance. Even in the code shown above, changing the declaration of the first line to `var sortedInquires` and removing to ` ToList` call at the end will make the whole operation more _LINQish_ and may improve performance and/or memory usage (in the general sense). The comment about performance is really only true if you delay _materalizing_ results till the end

Comment: The ToList() makes it easy to see results during debug.  All you have to do is hover mouse over variables.  Linq automatically wait until the end.  When you debug linq and step through code you will see linq will step backwards through code because it collects only the data that is needed dynamically.  If you are getting no results there is something with the join "a.Id equals i.Id" that is not matching.  I'm not doing a Left Outer Join (not needed) and you will only get results if the left object meets the right object.  I modified code slightly.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
var assignationsPerAgent = (from agent in agents
                                        join inq in inquires on agent equals inq.AsignedAgent into agentsInInquires
from inq in agentsInInquires.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            o_agent = agent,
                                            casesAssignedTo = agentsInInquires.Count()
                                        }).GroupBy(x=>x.casesAssignedTo).OrderBy(x=>x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This a Left Outer Join which is not needed.  The OP only want results where left side and right side match.

Comment: i have modified code please check and let me know @jdweng

Comment: Code will not work!!!  This makes no sense.  "agent equals inq.AsignedAgent"  Did you even bother to d a syntax check?

Comment: so tell me than what's the relation column between two table so we can add those instead of this condition @jdweng